# How can I dynamically change the field descriptions in Drupal when another field changes?

Tags: entities

Is there a module or does Drupal 7 have this already built in? Or can someone please explain how one can do this?

If you take a look at [Yelp's add business page](https://www.yelp.com/writeareview/newbiz?search_loc=United-States&fsid=UjUnLDl5ZfNylTKZzM2AiQ) you can see the description fields change when the user selects a different country. How can I do this with Drupal 7 on the node edit/add page?

Comment: there's https://drupal.org/project/ddf and https://drupal.org/project/conditional_fields

Comment: And built-in [#states](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#states) if you are willing to implement `hook_form_alter`. Please remember that [implementing a functionality, or a layout seen in a site, for which only a screenshot or a site URL is provided](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) is specifically off-topic, try to reword your question so it does not look that way.

Comment: Hi guys, I am currently using conditional fields but I don't believe it can do what I am asking above. Basically I would like to change the field description displayed above the field when selecting a specific country. For example, as you can see in the Yelp link I provided above, their is a field called location. When the user changes the country, it will have sample location text written above the field in the field description that pertains to that country. This is exactly what I would like to do. If this module can do this, please explain where the setting options are. Thanks!